# Read a image from folder when path in variable. Meteor blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to read image from folder. Image's path is mentioned in variable. And display.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for a solution, which was why I stumbled upon your question. Good news is, I fixed it!

Here's what I did:

```
let cityPic = "/images/city_" + this.props.city.name + ".png";
      cityPic = cityPic.toLowerCase();

return (    
      <div className="text-center"><img src={cityPic}></img></div>
)
```

I'm using React but I'm assuming it would work similarly.

Comment: Thank you... But we have to shift to some other solution. But I might be using for other assignments. Thank you once again.